# store two tables into a single table in mySQL

Tags: mysql

```
create table tempA (txt1 int(3))

insert into tempA(txt1) values(25),(null),(77),(44)

create table tempA1 (txt2 int(3))

insert into tempA1 (txt2) values (null),(null),(null),(11),(88)
```

Can any one suggest me, to insert these two table into a single table(*tempA and tempA1*) into **temp** table. But the condition is like the **temp** table should hold only the values.

Thanks in Advances

Comment: you mean store only not null values on temp table ?

Comment: Yes, HamoonDBA.

Comment: `insert into ... select ... where ... is not null`. Isn't so hard, isn't it?

Comment: so mean like this                                                                                          insert into tempA select * from tempA1 where txt1 is not null and txt2 is not null

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stream changes from tempA and tempA1 to temp, you can use trigger to do this
create trigger for both tables

Example:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_to_temp` AFTER INSERT
ON `tempa`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    if new.txt1 is not null THEN
        insert into temp values(new.txt1);
 END IF;
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

And do this for tempa1

but if you want to do a batch insert you can run:

```
insert into temp select * from tempa where txt1 is not null union select * from tempa1 where txt2 is not null
```